# mod_proxy with tomcat7 gives error 502 when uploading files

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

So, I have an apache 2.2.16 (64 bit) installed on a Debian Server. I have configured a proxy, for a specific url to map to my backend Tomcat 7 server.

Everything works fine for all of the GET/POST requests except for multipart POST requests. The error log of apache is showing the followinf lines:

```
[error] [client CLIENT_IP] (20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server TOMCAT_IP:8081
[error] [client CLIENT_IP] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /svc/document
```

Strange thing is that POST multipart works fine if I upload a ZERO Kb file, but fails with other files (no more than a few bytes). And everything, including uploads works fine on my developing environment (XAMPP + mod_proxy + tomcat)

Tomcat 7 connector:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="TOMCAT_IP" maxThreads="6000"
               connectionTimeout="40000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" maxPostSize="8388608" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Proxy is configured as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend/
      ServerName frontend.com

      ProxyPass /svc/ http://[TOMCAT_IP]:8081/web/ connectiontimeout=40 timeout=60 Keepalive=On min=20 acquire=20 retry=1
 </VirtualHost>
```

I even tried some suggestions, one by one and all in once, as found on similar question, but with no luck:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend/
  ServerName frontend.com

  ProxyPass /svc/ http://[TOMCAT_IP]:8081/web/ connectiontimeout=40 timeout=60 Keepalive=On min=20 acquire=20 retry=1

  ProxyBadHeader Ignore
  ProxyRequests Off
  LimitRequestBody 8388608
  SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried ProxyPassReverse, raise timeout, ProxyBadHeader Ignore, setenv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1 etc. nothing seems to work... Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution a while ago, 
I'm posting it for future reference.

The problem was neither Tomcat nor Apache. 
The problem was in the underlying network. The connection between the 2 servers, provided as a separate link by the ISP was missing/had a bad MTU parameter configuration. This was causing the network to drop frames bigger than a certain number of bytes.
Once the MTU was set explicitly to 1500 problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the error was not in "Apache".

I think the first step, you need request the upload in direct tomcat url.

Sample with curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://[YOUR IP OR LOCALHOST]:8081/web \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 406bfbe4-94d3-0c70-1b0f-0d1fdb2a6f5b' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'uploadFile=@20180703_1409164.mp4'
```

By making the request direct to tomcat, you will be sure that the error is not from httpd.

if you receive a  malformed server response and, to ignore it, we could set this option on our httpd.conf:

```
ProxyBadHeader Ignore
```

After this change, it finally revealed to you the real problem.

Usually errors are caused by some upload limit.

You can increment the limit in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  redirectPort="8443"
  maxSwallowSize = "-1"/>
```

or if you problem is timeout :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" disableUploadTimeout="false"
           connectionTimeout="60000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

More information:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maxuploadsizeexceeded

http://somepixels.net/en/502-proxy-error-uploading-from-apache-mod_proxy-to-tomcat-7/

Comment: `maxSwallowSize = "-1"` did the trick for me, thanks a bunch!